# Linker command failed with Undefined symbols for architecture i386

Tags: iphone, ios4, catransition, page-curl

i am trying to do the half page curl feature.  This is the code I am using:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>


CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[animation setDelegate:self];
[animation setDuration:1.0f];
[animation setTimingFunction:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[animation setType:(notCurled ? @"mapCurl" : @"mapUnCurl")];
[animation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
[animation setFillMode: @"extended"];
[animation setRemovedOnCompletion: NO];
notCurled = !notCurled;
```

But I encounter the following errors

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CATransition", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MyMapViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CATransition", referenced from:


      objc-class-ref in SJMapViewController.o


ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386


clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

your app is complaining it can not find CATransition Symbol.

Did you add the QuartzCore framework to your app?

If not add it: go to your target settings -> build phases -> link binary -> select the + button and select QuartzCore.

then import it where you  need to use it:

```
      #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Comment: I thought I had added the framework, rechecked it and found that I haven't added. Thanks mate.

Comment: Had this same problem but it had to do with code that I imported into my project from another library. In case anyone has that issue go into Build Phases and add the imported files to Compile Sources.

Comment: Thanks, @robhasacamera, that's exactly what I needed. Couldn't figure out why I was still having the problem with the framework and imports set up correctly.